# Extract 189 columns from 189 files and make a new data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have 189 files I must read all of them and extract one column form these files and make a new data frame based on these columns, could you please help me to write a function in R?

```
number<-189 #number of files
cnt<-5
for(i in 1:number){
  cnt<-cnt+1
  print(i)
  dfn<-as.data.frame(fread(paste0("Trait",cnt,".SOL"),
                           colClasses =c("character")))
  row<-which(dfn==nrow(dfn))
  E<-as.data.frame(dfn[,8])
  

}
```

I write this loop but unfortunately just read one file

Comment: You are reading all of the files, but you overwrite `E` on each pass through the loop so you only get column 8 of the last file. You need to create `E` before the loop (`E <- NULL`) and then add each column within the loop with E <- cbind(E, dfn[, 8])`. You probably do not need `as.data.frame()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a directory full of files and you want to read them all in and extract one column from each file, you can use the `list.files()` function to get a list of all the files in the directory, then loop through that list and read each file in using the `read.table()` function. You can extract the column you want using the `$` operator.

Here's an example:

```
# get a list of all the files in the directory
file_list <- list.files()

# loop through the list of files
for(i in 1:length(file_list)){
  
  # read in the file
  data <- read.table(file_list[i])
  
  # extract the column you want
  column <- data$column_name
  
  # do something with the column data...
  
}
```

You can also use the `lapply()` function to read in all the files and extract the column you want in one line:

```
# get a list of all the files in the directory
file_list <- list.files()

# read in all the files and extract the column you want
column_list <- lapply(file_list, function(x) read.table(x)$column_name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, after I read all data and select the columns how can I put them in a new data frame?